# How to extract the text 5 from the text node within the parent div node using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract a text from `<div>`, which is an inside double quote (refer Screenshot) with **XPath**

```
<div class="two columns" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px;">
  <img src="images/spins_s.png" border="0" style="margin-bottom: -1px;"> 
   5
</div>
```

I am attaching a screenshot here,
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOmeS.png][1]
While i am trying this xpath expression in cole log its return **correct o/p**,

```
>>$x("//div[@class='two columns']/img[@src='images/spins_s.png']/..")[0].innerText
>>" 5"
```

But when I am going to run this **code** In python

```
spin_balance = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='two columns']/img[@src='images/spins_s.png']/..")[0].innerText
```

it's giving **error** like this

```
spin_balance = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='two columns']/img[@src='images/spins_s.png']/..")[0].innerText
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable
```

Image of HTML:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text ***5*** is within a text node. So to print the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.two.columns"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='two columns']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *childNodes*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='two columns'][./img[@src='images/spins_s.png']]")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='two columns'][./img[@src='images/spins_s.png']]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[2])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```